# Include Has One Attached via raw SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

Is there a way to use raw sql to include a user's (profile) avatar url?

```rb
# profile.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one_attached :avatar

# user.rb
has_one :profile
```

I only need a little information from the `profiles` table including the `avatar_url`:

```rb
sql = "Select 
        u.id as user_id,
        --- I need the avatar_ul to be in the select:
        --- p.blah as avatar_url,
        p.name
      FROM 
        users as u
      JOIN 
        profiles as p 
        ON u.id = p.user_id
      WHERE u.department_id = 1
    "
 # This will work fine:
User.find_by_sql(sql).to_json
```

I'm looking at `active_storage_blobs` but have no clue how to include that in the sql query. All I need is to select few columns and return a `json` format. I would expect to get the full url to the image (avatar).

Currently using PostgreSQL as database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [url_for](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#redirect-mode) is what generates the `signed_id` and I assume the only way is by:

```rb
arr = []

# All users
User.all.each do | user |
  arr.push(
    {
      id: user.id, 
      name: user.profile.name, 
      avatar_url: user.profile.avatar.attached? && Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(user.profile.avatar, only_path: true)
    }
  )
end
```

I do not like this approach but I'll run with it for now, unless someone can come up with a better way of doing it.